# How to check if an object has an attribute, even Optional?

Tags: python, python-typing

I was wondering if there was a way to list every attribute of a class, discriminating between optional and non-optional.

This method would ideally be able to handle the following example:

```py
from typing import Dict, Optional, Union

class TestClass:
    id: int
    name: Optional[str]

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(testclass_dict: Dict[str, Union[int, str]]):
        test: TestClass = TestClass()
        non_opt_attributes, opt_attributes = attributes_lister(TestClass)
        for attribute_name in non_opt_attributes:
            try:
                setattr(test, attribute_name, testclass_dict[attribute_name])
            except KeyError as ke:
                print(f"{attribute_name} is a non optional attribute of TestClass")
                return None
        for attribute in opt_attributes:
            try:
                setattr(test, attribute_name, testclass_dict[attribute_name])
            except KeyError as ke:
                setattr(test, attribute_name, None)
        return test
```

This would then have this result:

```py
test1: TestClass = TestClass.from_dict({"name": "name"})
test2: TestClass = TestClass.from_dict({"id": 5})
test3: TestClass = TestClass.from_dict({"id": 5, "name": "name"})
test4: TestClass = TestClass.from_dict({"id": 5, "name": "name", "random": "value"})
```

```py
test1 = None
test2 = TestClass(id=5)
test3 = TestClass(id=5, name="name")
test4 = TestClass(id=5, name="name")
```

### EDIT

I corrected my code following [@user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112)'s comment that `Optional` doesn't authorize absence, but simply for it to be `None`.
That said, I don't see it having too much of an impact on the original question.

Comment: `Optional` means "maybe `None`", not "maybe absent".

Comment: Your dataclass has two fields, just assign them manually, without any _attributes listing_ shenanigans. And if you want to check for incoming data correctness, you can always use a simple Json schema validator.

Comment: Yes, this example here has two fields. This is obviously not the case for the application I have in mind. Additionally, assigning them manually multiplies the places where it has to be changed in case of new attributes / attribute removal / attribute modification, and is thus more error-prone in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Using default field values in a `dataclass` with a proper validation:

```
import functools
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional, Callable, TypeVar, Type

import jsonschema

_T = TypeVar("_T")
SCHEMA_DIALECT = {"$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#"}


def validate_schema(schema: dict = None) -> Callable:
    """
    A decorator that applies a jsonschema validation for the `input_object`.
    If `schema` is None, `cls` is required to provide a `_get_schema` method
    which returns a schema to validate against.

    Decorated function may use `validation_handler` keyword parameter to pass a function:
        f(err: ValidationError, input_object: dict, schema: dict)
    which will be used to handle a validation exception if it occurs (or raise an error if
    there's no handler).
    """

    def dec(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapper(cls: type, input_object: dict, **kwargs):
            try:
                jsonschema.validate(
                    input_object, schema if schema else cls._get_schema()
                )
            except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as e:
                if handler := kwargs.get("validation_handler"):
                    handler(err=e, input_object=input_object, schema=schema)
                else:
                    raise e
            return f(cls, input_object)

        return wrapper

    return dec


@dataclass
class TestClass:
    _id: int
    name: Optional[str] = "Default name"

    @classmethod
    @validate_schema()
    def from_dict(cls: Type[_T], data: dict) -> _T:
        return cls(**data)

    @classmethod
    def _get_schema(cls) -> dict:
        return SCHEMA_DIALECT | {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": False,
            "required": ["_id"],
            "properties": {
                "_id": {"title": "ID", "type": "integer"},
                "name": {
                    "title": "Name",
                    "type": ["string", "null"],
                    "default": "null",
                },
            },
        }
```

And then

```
TestClass.from_dict({
    'nonexistent key': 'whatever value'
})
```

gives `ValidationError: Additional properties are not allowed ('nonexistent key' was unexpected)`;

```
TestClass.from_dict({
    '_id': 'not an integer'
})
```

gives `ValidationError: 'not an integer' is not of type 'integer'`;

```
TestClass.from_dict({
    '_id': 1
})
```

gives `TestClass(_id=1, name='Default name')`;

```
TestClass.from_dict({
    '_id': 1,
    'name': 'Non-default name'
})
```

gives `TestClass(_id=1, name='Non-default name')`.

Which are all expected results with literally no code in `from_dict` method.

This also gives you more control of any future structure changes and enables a pretty straightforward `as_dict` method if you wanted to implement it too.

Comment: This would be a good solution, I will try and implement it. Is there any way to access the declaration of the fields? This would allow to generate the `JSON Schema` or event remove the need for it.

Comment: Sure, [`pydantic`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/json_schema/) can do this for you.